# Wordpress Index.php blog post

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

Im struggling structuring my blog post layout. I need to be able to put a form between all my article blog post. I'm not sure how to put the form between all of the post. I'm not sure if this making sense but heres my code. My CSS parents I used flex box

**Right layout:**

[image: Right layout expected:]

**Wrong layout currently I have:**

[image: Wrong layout]

**Here's my code:**

[image]

Comment: Don't paste code as image please.

Comment: Try to copy & paste the codes (especially HTML structure & CSS) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You store the data in a array variable from the_post() query. You will get the array length and you can use looping such as for loop or while loop. Example:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $array_length ; $i++) { 
  if ($i == 1){
    //Here you can write the form block
  }
  else{
    //continue to write the post block
  }
}
```